# R script to find peptides after trypsin digest in databases/literature

Tags: r, automation, sequence, bioinformatics, digest

I have a long list of peptide sequences which I would like to look up in batch mode in public sources/ databases, to see if the peptides have been identified as biomarkers in specific tissues (plasma, urine, etc). The problem is that the peptides have been generated using a trypsin digest, which means that I do not always get exact matches and need to also find inexact matches to my peptide queries by finding cases with irregular digest cleavages. The only R packages I am finding that can handle issues with enzyme digests deal with spectra rather than peptide sequences. I would appreciate any suggestions on how to do this, thanks!

Comment: You might want to add the tag `Bioinformatics` so the right people will find your post.

Comment: you should ask biostars.org

Answer (score 0):

I've used the "Cleaver" R package in the past, it seems to have the most comprehensive list of enzymes that I've come across yet:

devtools::install_github("sgibb/cleaver")